# Determination of a cost function in optimal control

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, control-theory

I'm working on learning optimal control and I can't figure out how to reduce this equation.

What I know:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} x(t)^{T}Qx(t) + 2x(t)^{T}Su(t) + u(t)^{T}Ru(t) dt$$
$$u = -R^{-1}S^{T}x + v$$

Q is symmetric, R is positive definite

The resulting cost function should be:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} x(t)^{T}Qx(t) + v(t)^{T}Rv(t) dt$$

The work I have done so far has led me to a what seems like a dead end. I am not sure how to achieve the result.

My work:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} x(t)^{T}Qx(t) + 2x(t)^{T}S(-R^{-1}S^{T}x + v) + (-R^{-1}S^{T}x + v)^{T}R(-R^{-1}S^{T}x + v) dt$$

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} x(t)^{T}Qx(t) - 2x(t)^{T}SR^{-1}S^{T}x + 2x(t)^{T}Sv + (-x^{T}SR^{-T} + v^{T})R(-R^{-1}S^{T}x + v) dt$$

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} x(t)^{T}Qx(t) - 2x(t)^{T}SR^{-1}S^{T}x + 2x(t)^{T}Sv + (-x^{T}SR^{-T}R + v^{T}R)(-R^{-1}S^{T}x + v) dt$$

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} x(t)^{T}Qx(t) - 2x(t)^{T}SR^{-1}S^{T}x + 2x(t)^{T}Sv + x^{T}SR^{-T}RR^{-1}S^{T}x -x^{T}SR^{-T}Rv - v^{T}RR^{-1}S^{T}x + v^{T}Rv dt$$

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} x(t)^{T}Qx(t) - 2x(t)^{T}SR^{-1}S^{T}x + 2x(t)^{T}Sv + x^{T}SR^{-T}S^{T}x -x^{T}SR^{-T}Rv - v^{T}S^{T}x + v^{T}Rv dt$$

I'm not really sure where to go from here.

Comment: What you give is not an **equation** because there is no **equal sign**. it is an expression. Do you have to minimize, maximize it ?

Comment: i have taken the liberty to modify your title in order for it to be more attractive to people who are acquainted with the domain. I have also added the tag "quadratic form" ($x^TQx$ is a quadratic form).

Comment: Good point! I am starting with the first cost function that has a "cross-term" defined as S. I am given an input u and must show how, given the input, I can formulate the cost function as the resulting function $x^{T}Qx + v^{T}Rv$

Comment: Just a remark: Get rid of the first term it is not necessary to keep track of it as it is already included in the final answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the fact that $R=R^{\top}$. Even if this is not the case, you can make it so. In order to see why I will denote the final result for the integral with $J$ which is scalar, so it should always be true that $J=(J+J^{\top}\!)/2$. By doing this also to all the terms inside the integral it can be shown that you get the same answer if you redefine $R$ as $(R+R^{\top}\!)/2$, which is symmetric. The same can not be said about $S$, but you can use that the cross term is scalar and therefore $v^{\top}S^{\top}x=x^{\top}S\,v$. This is also why there is a $2$ in the original equation, because it can also be written as

$$
\int_0^\infty \begin{bmatrix}x \\ u\end{bmatrix}^\top \begin{bmatrix}Q & S \\ S^\top & R\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x \\ u\end{bmatrix} dt
$$

Substituting in that $R=R^{\top}$ and that cross term is also equal to its transpose into your last expression allows it to be simplified to

$$
\int_0^\infty x^\top Q\,x - 2\,x^\top S\,R^{-1}S^\top x + 2\,x^\top S\,v + x^\top S\,R^{-1}S^\top x - x^\top S\,R^{-1}R\,v - x^\top S\,v + v^\top R\,v\,dt
$$

$$
\int_0^\infty x^\top\!\left(Q - S\,R^{-1}S^\top\right)x + v^\top\!R\,v\, dt
$$

The finial expression inside the integral is not identical to $x^\top\!Q\,x + v^\top\!R\,v$, because there aren't in general. But you can view the matrix within the brackets in the quadratic term of $x$, $Q - S\,R^{-1}S^\top$, as the new $Q$ matrix.

In order for there to be a solution to the LQR problem it does require that this new $Q$ matrix is positive semi-definite. This requirement is identical to the requirement of that

$$
\begin{bmatrix}Q & S \\ S^\top & R\end{bmatrix}
$$

is positive semi-definite as well, with $R$ still positive definite. So if the LQR problem is solvable for the following weighting matrices $(Q,R,S)$, then it will also be solvable when using $(Q-S\,R^{-1}S^\top,R,0)$ as weighting matrices.

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense to me.